# Split an rle object

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following rle object:

```
r = rle(c(rep("M",28),rep("N",4265),rep("M",16),rep("S",2),rep("N",400),rep("M",10)));
```

And I want to break it down to the following vector of strings:

```
a = c("28M","4265N","16M2S","400N","10M");
```

Meaning I separate "N" values and non "N" values and their corresponding lengths into separate elements in a vector.

Please note that all the non Ns are paste togetherm that is why the result has "16M2S", and not "16M" "2S" separated.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: There are number of functions for dealing with cigars in the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package, with a bit of a learning curve but fairly extensive help pages, e.g., `?cigarToRleList`, `cigar<tab>`

Comment: no need to end lines with semicolons in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works and should be decent speedwise:

```
l <- r$lengths
v <- r$values
s <- paste0(l, v)
n <- v == "N"
i <- cumsum(c(TRUE, head(n, -1) != tail(n, -1)))

unname(vapply(split(s, i), paste, character(1), collapse = ""))
# [1] "28M"   "4265N" "16M2S" "400N"  "10M"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
r2 <- rle(r$values == "N")

len <- r2$lengths

spl <- rep(seq_along(len), len)

len2 <- split(r$lengths, spl)

val <- split(r$values, spl)

mapply(paste0, len2, val, collapse = "", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] "28M"   "4265N" "16M2S" "400N"  "10M"
```